# Can I assign an AD network by country in Admob mediation?

Tags: android, admob

I just found that the AD network that I currently use can support Admob mediation. I would like to give it a try so I can utilize both network. After some code change, I found that all ads shows in my app are from Admob instead of coming from my preferred provider. (I do see some request to my original provider with returned error code: NO_FILL)

So, my question is simple, can I assign an AD network to specific country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. Go into Admob dashboard
2. Choose your app and adUnit
3. Select the network (left hand side checkbox)
4. Click on Edit in the Country specific settings (right hand side)

But if you are getting a response of NO_FILL from your preferred provider then it means that Admob is asking them for an ad first, and is being told they have no ad to display, so it falls back to Admob. This is **exactly** why you use mediation.

Comment: thx. But I only found the field called eCPM. How much should I set if I want all traffic from country A to use provider B?

Comment: You give it the highest eCPM value. That way it will always be asked first. If it has no ad then the others will be asked.